# Using `vars_prompt` on Task file

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-role

Trying to use `vars_prompt` on `main.yml` task inside role but I get error:

tasks/main.yml file for role 'roleName' must contain a list of tasks

```
  vars_prompt:
    - name: 'variableName'
      prompt: "Prompting User "
      private: no
      default: ''

  - name: taskName
    uri:
      url: "{{ variableName }}"
    register: response
    ignore_errors: yes
  - debug:
      var: response
```

If I move the prompting to playbook `main.yml` it works but I need to be able to do it within the task.
Thoughts?

Comment: Declaration of "tasks:" before "- name: taskName" is missing.

Comment: This is invalid YAML, you cannot have both key-value pairs and sequence items at under the same node (i.e. the root level). Please update your post with the corrected YAML.

Answer (score 6):

`vars_prompt` can only be defined [on a play](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html).  A task list is so named because it can only consist of tasks; metadata like `vars`, `vars_prompt`, `hosts`, etc. can only be set at the play level.

Consider avoiding the use of `vars_prompt` if at all possible. If you need input from the user, have them provide it on the command line using `-e variable=value` or in a file and using `-e @somefile.yml`.